# cakephp how can i tell before function from an update

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am working on a CakePHP 2.x. The scenario is I am sending an encrypted and decrypted data to the database. So in order to do this I have written `beforeSave` function in each modal. 
so right now the problem is whenever data is updated, the data is not going encrypted into db .. please anyone know how to i fix this issue

I am doing this in my controller. The update and save function:

```
    foreach($data as $datas){
    $count = $this->Contact->checkkey($datas['idUser'],$datas['key']); 
    if($count>0){
                $this->Contact->updateContactAgainstkey($datas['name'],
                    $this->request->data['Contact']['mobileNo'],
                    $this->request->data['Contact']['other'],
                    $this->request->data['Contact']['email'],
                    $datas['key'],$datas['idUser']);
            }else{
                $this->Contact->create();
                $this->Contact->save($this->request->data);
          }
     }
```

updateFunction in Model

```
      public function updateContactAgainstkey($name,$mobileNo,
                                       $other,$email,$key,$userid){


    if($this->updateAll(
        array('name' => "'$name'",
            'mobileNo' => "'$mobileNo'",
            'workNo' => "'$workNo'",
            'homeNo' => "'$homeNo'",
            'other' => "'$other'",
            'email' => "'$email'",),
        array('User_id'=>$userid,'key'=>$key))){

        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

beforeSave function

```
 public function beforeSave($options=array()) {

    if  ( isset ( $this -> data [ $this -> alias ] [ 'mobileNo' ] ) )  {
        $this -> data [ $this -> alias ] [ 'mobileNo' ]  =  AllSecure::encrypt($this->data[$this->alias]['email']);
    }


    return true;
}
```

please help me if anyone know how to deal with this issue.

Comment: what is updateContactAgainstkey?

Comment: Why are you using both double and single quotes here: `"'$name'"` ?

Comment: well i dont know .. i just have found the solution over the net when i was searching how to update the data in cake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here better to use save function for updating data like:

```
$data=array();
$data['Contact']['mobileNo']=$this->request->data['Contact']['mobileNo'];
$data['Contact']['other']=$this->request->data['Contact']['other'];
$data['Contact']['other']=$this->request->data['Contact']['other'];
........... .............. ................
$this->Contact->id = "primerykey";
$this->Contact->save($data);
```

where $data contains all field that you want to update with value

Comment: $this->Contact->id = "primerykey"; this line comes as it is .. or should i have to write something "primarykey" here .. well i want u to know that i have specifiec in my modal the primary key .. like that public $primarykey="idContacts"

Comment: and in ur where do i tell that update where key and user id is this ?

Comment: use $this->Contact->id = $datas['key'];

Comment: well key is not a primary key ... i have a seperate key column in my table .. which is unique ... i am updating against it

Comment: but at the update time obvious you will get primary key for that record,anyway am trying something else...

Comment: well actually i am getting data from the android ..thats why.. i have to update against the key and userid

Comment: for your reference https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2459-model-updateall-does-not-trigger-the-aftersave-callback

Answer (score 2):

Try following code in model

```
public function updateAll($fields, $conditions = true) {
    $db =& ConnectionManager::getDataSource($this->useDbConfig);
    $created = FALSE;
    $options = array();
    if($db->update($this, $fields, null, $conditions)) {
      $created = TRUE;
      $this->Behaviors->trigger($this, 'afterSave', array($created, $options));
      $this->afterSave($created);
      $this->_clearCache();
      $this->id = false;
      return true;
    }
  return FALSE;
 }
```

look here
http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2010/01/27/make-updateall-fire-behavior-callbacks/

Comment: well thankyou for your answer ..well i didnt try your code yet ..but i worked it by my own ..what i did is i have try ur old code and then get the primary code through key ... and then i pass the primary id to the $this->Contact->id ... and it works